# Как покрасить отдельные символы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

Делаю скрипт, который отправляет погоду. Чтобы все было красиво решил добавить иконку погоды в стиле ascii-art. Вроде сделал, но нужно покрасить солнышко в желтый, а облако оставить белым. Пытаюсь сделать через *colorama*, но он красит мне пол солнца, а остальное не красит. Вот код:

```
print(r'          \ ___ /  ')
print(r'       .--./   \ __ ')
print(r'    .-(    )___/ ' )
print(r'   (___.__.____)\ ')
```

---

Как покрасить солнце в желтый, а облако оставить белым?

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста на этом сайте: https://all-python.ru/osnovy/tsvetnoj-vyvod-teksta.html#vyvod-tsvetnogo-teksta-v-konsol-s-colorama Может быть здесь вы найдёте полезную информацию

Comment: а где вы в этом коде пытаетесь что-то сделать через колораму?

Comment: @Эникейщик поздно было, я все убрал, решил залить так. Но суть была такая: я красил первый print: \ __ / + Fore.YELLOW и у меня красилось все остальное, кроме этой строчки. Потом еще много чего перепробовал, но в итоге - увы

Comment: @CameUp указание цвета влияет только на текст, идущий после него. Т.е. чтобы строку покрасить нужно делать так: `print(Fore.YELLOW + r'          \ ___ /  ')`

Comment: @insolor спасибо, я все голову ломал. Программировал весь день, к 3-ем часам ночи документацию читал так, что не читал)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если коротко: перед выводом символа выводить нужный цвет (или как минимум выводить цвет, если цвет не совпадает с цветом предыдущих символов).

Идея такая: дополнительно к текстовой картинке облака делаем текстовую картинку, в которой разными буквами обозначены разные цвета, параллельно посимвольно читаем обе текстовые строки, меняем цвет в соответствии с символом из второй строки, потом выводим символ из первой строки.

Все примерно как в этом ответе, только там каждый символ картинки сам задавал свой цвет:
[Как задать всем символам x черный цвет, y - зеленый, z - красный, i - желтый?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1241809/1365)

Пример кода:

```
import itertools

import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style


colorama.init()

cloud = r"""
          \ ___ /
       .--./   \ __
    .-(    )___/
   (___.__.____)\
""".splitlines()[1:]

# Изначально скопировал текст облака, потом каждый символ заменил на символ цвета (Y будет желтым, W - белым)
colors = """
          Y YYY Y
       WWWWY   Y YY
    WWW    WWWWY
   WWWWWWWWWWWWWY
""".splitlines()[1:]

# Задаем соответствие, что Y будем менять на желтый цвет, W - на белый
color_map = {
    'Y': Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW,
    'W': Style.BRIGHT + Fore.WHITE
}

prev_color = Style.NORMAL + Fore.WHITE
print(prev_color, end='')
for image_line, color_line in zip(cloud, colors):
    for symbol, color_char in itertools.zip_longest(image_line, color_line, fillvalue=''):
        color = color_map.get(color_char)
        # Если символу соответствует какой-то цвет, и цвет не совпадает с предыдущим цветом, то меняем цвет
        if color and color != prev_color:
            prev_color = color
            print(color, end='')
        
        print(symbol, end='')
    print()

print(Style.RESET_ALL, end='')
```

Изначально делал просто две текстовые строки, а не два списка строк (не разбивал строки с помощью `splitlines`), но когда строчки внутри текста разной длины, цвета начинают смещаться, а с разбивкой на отдельные строки проще контролировать соответствие цветов символам на картинке.

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Выглядит красиво :)

Comment: Да, мне тоже нравится, как в итоге получилось)